# Can the WriteFile() function just stop working?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

I have a windows program written in C++. It periodically writes information to a text file using `WriteFile()` WinAPI function.

The program opens the file when it starts and leaves the file opened until it exits. The program opens the file using this code:

```
CreateFileW(path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, &sa,
    OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

The following problem has occured recently: after running about 10 days the program stopped writing information to the file. But when the program was restarted, it resumed writing to the file.

Suppose the program has no bugs and WriteFile continues to be invoked to write data: can the `WriteFile` function just start failing after some period of normal working? What can cause this? 
(Except disk space problems. The file is rather small and disk has enough space).

(unfortunately the program does not check the `WriteFile`'s return value).

Comment: I don't know why it failed, but then again you shouldn't keep files open for that long. Assuming it's a log file, the normal practice is to close and reopen it after a time- and/or a volume- threshold are reached (Often, the volume threshold is "one log entry"). You should also recycle logs, i.e., at midnight, close and rename the current output file with a date-stamp, then start a new log when the next entry is ready to be written.

Comment: Any number of things could cause a write failure, and if there's a failure then it's quite possible that subsequent writes will fail. Some possibilities: out of memory, too many writes pending, intermittent hardware failure. If you're not checking the return value of `WriteFile`, then all you can do is speculate.

Comment: (unrelated): you can use `FILE_APPEND_DATA` instead of `GENERIC_WRITE`

Comment: Check out the MSDN entry for WriteFile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) There are many reasons the function could fail. If you don't have access to the source code of the application to add error checking to the function consider using a tool such as FileMon from SysInternals to monitor file writes. I don't know how well the tool can perform over long periods of time but perhaps you will find it helpful anyway.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos , what's wrong with keeping files open for a long time? Can it lead to WriteFile failure? I keep it open to make sure that no other app will open it and prohibit write access to it for my application.

Comment: @smsrecv: You also shouldn't depend on open file handles to prevent unauthorised writes. That's what permissions and ACLs are for. If your application crashes for some reason, then other processes can write to it while it's down. The fact that you are here asking the question should be reason enough to conclude that keeping files open for a long time is a bad idea. Stuff goes bad all the time; minimising the dependence on long-lasting state is an important element of writing tough code that just keeps on working.

Comment: Also, there exist programs (such as [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html)) that allow the user to force close an open handles. Could this be the source of your problem? I guess the only sure way of finding out would be to see what `GetLastError()` returns, if you could reproduce the issue.

Comment: How did you determine that it was the WriteFile that failed and not some other aspect of the program so that it simply stopped trying to write to the log file?

Comment: "_unfortunately the program does not check the WriteFile's return value_" - you should **always** check WinAPI return values and do proper error handing and reporting.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty implausible that the `WriteFile()` API function has a bug. Your next step must be to check error codes and call `GetLastError()` when the function fails.

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing that can lead to that is :

- when Windows stops hard drive for energy economy, the file is closed or
- also when it goes in standby mode

Answer (score 0):

WriteFile function in our case was failing because we had called the function in the timer. There was another function in a thread which was calling ReadFile (and accessing the same file) in a parallel thread. Since the WriteFile did not get the access to the file at that instance, it used to fail!

Comment: you should simply add this as a comment.